# tcp application exit will send FIN always?

Tags: tcp, network-programming, client-server, network-protocols

When a TCP application exits it will  send a FIN packet.

Consider a tcp client which get connected to a always listening server(server never exits).

if the tcp client is exiting abruptly after few exchange of packets, will it always send a FIN packet to the server?

Thx!

Comment: It depends on the operating system. Unix and derivatives behave as you describe. WIndows does not: when an application running on Windows exits without closing a TCP socket, the TCP connection will be reset, not terminated normally via a FIN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under normal operation , a FIN will be sent ,yes.

Here's a few cases where a FIN is not going to be sent.

- Someone yanks out the network cable of the client.
- The client gets nuked
- The FIN packets are dropped on the way.
- The OS on the kernel crashes hard.

Comment: I think close call is necessary to send a FIN correct?
Even if the client does not call close call, wil it be sent?

Comment: Yes, even if the application does not close the connection the OS will do it for you when/after the application exits, and a FIN will be sent,(or a RST depending on the connection state, e.g. if there's unprocessed incoming data )